# log4perl: How to write ERROR message to file and DEBUG message to stderr?

Tags: perl, logging

I want to write ERROR message to a file, and write DEBUG message to stderr, then I write the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);

Log::Log4perl->easy_init(
        {
            file  => ">> error_log",
            level => $ERROR,
        },
        {
            file  => "STDERR",
            level => $DEBUG,
        }
        );

ERROR( "ERROR MESSAGE" );
DEBUG( "DEBUG MESSAGE" );
```

When I run the above code, the message `ERROR MESSAGE` and `DEBUG MESSAGE` write to both file and stderr, can anyone explain why?

Comment: Maybe use a custom filter, see: [How to set two appenders with different log levels in Log::Log4perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33306035/2173773)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve both output to file and screen for different levels and the same category, you can use [a custom filter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::Filter). For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);

my $conf   = <<'EOF';
log4perl.rootLogger             = DEBUG, file, screen
log4perl.filter.MatchDebug = Log::Log4perl::Filter::LevelMatch
log4perl.filter.MatchDebug.LevelToMatch  = DEBUG
log4perl.filter.MatchDebug.AcceptOnMatch = true

log4perl.filter.MatchError = Log::Log4perl::Filter::LevelMatch
log4perl.filter.MatchError.LevelToMatch  = ERROR
log4perl.filter.MatchError.AcceptOnMatch = true

log4perl.appender.file          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.file.filename = error_log.txt
log4perl.appender.file.mode     = append
log4perl.appender.file.utf8     = 1
log4perl.appender.file.Filter   = MatchError
log4perl.appender.file.layout   = SimpleLayout

log4perl.appender.screen         = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
log4perl.appender.screen.stderr  = 1
log4perl.appender.screen.utf8    = 1
log4perl.appender.screen.Filter   = MatchDebug
log4perl.appender.screen.layout   = SimpleLayout
EOF

Log::Log4perl::init( \$conf );
ERROR( "ERROR MESSAGE" );
DEBUG( "DEBUG MESSAGE" );
```

See also [How to set two appenders with different log levels in Log::Log4perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33306035/2173773)